# How to reduce table size for date data type?

Tags: mysql

I was saving data for a table, as follows.

```
create table A
(
    RecordDate date not null, -- 3 bytes 
    SomeNumber int not null, -- 4 bytes 
)
```

For each single calendar day, about 20 thousands records for table A are created, with the same RecordDate, but different SomeNumber. That makes the RecordDate redundant for many records, I felt that there is some room to reduce the table size. Is there a way I can cut table A's size without losing the date information? Thanks.

Comment: How many orders per day are you expecting? Unless it's several thousand I can't see a situation where the relative space of a date column would make a dent in any modern database. Also are you sure you only want to store the date? If you have a row for every order you might as well store the time, it's a very useful statistic.

Comment: I don't see a scope of optimization here. If this is on some embedded device and you have sever restriction of space, you can store the date with start order and end order for the day in another table, but it is going to be a nightmare when you want to retrieve data.

Comment: it's about 20 thousands records added per day.

Comment: I can't see redundancy here. Note that order is a reserved word

Comment: 20k records per day times 3 bytes is 60kb/day or ~20Mb/year, assuming 24x7 operation, excluding indexes. Hardly enough to worry about. The rest of the order row is going to be an ordier of magnitude or two the size of the date cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, I don't think it is worth the effort in your case, even with 20,000 transactions per day. I suspect it's not worthwhile for millions of transactions per day. A 'Date' field uses 3 bytes of data, which is already one of the smallest datatypes in your database.

However, I think it's an interesting question.

Bansi's suggestion is a very space efficient solution (have a date table with min and max order number) but without any table keys you could (would) break your data, and it would be very hard to fix or even know it's broken. You would also massively increase your query time, as it would have to make two calculations on every record to find dates within a range.

**My solution** would be a dimensional modeling style date table, with a date key and the date. Your transaction table would store a date key for you to join to. For this to be of any benefit the date key would have to be a 'smallint' type (2 bytes). You would save 1 byte per row minus a relatively insignificant amount for the date table itself.

Note that using 'smallint' restricts your number of dates to 65,535 different days, or ~180 years if the days are consecutive.

Comment: Thanks Max, and you all. I thought it over based on your suggestions. You  guys are right, it may not be worthwhile to change it. Thanks for showing all the alternatives!